# How does the applicant counter work on LinkedIn?

Tags: linkedin

I saw this internship posting on LinkedIn:

[image]

How does the applicant counter work on LinkedIn? I find it hard to believe that 558 were sent in one day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My assumption is that the counter is highly inaccurate. I did hit the "Apply on the company website" button once by accident and surprisingly found the counter was incremented on the LinkedIn page, even though I did not proceed with application. I checked this few times later, every time you hit that button (apparently from unique profile) the counter goes up by one, but I do not take that counter seriously anymore